# Is it better to write the subscript or the superscript first (e.g. x_a^i vs x^i_a)?

Tags: math-mode, best-practices, subscripts, superscripts

Is it better to write subscripts or superscripts first (e.g. `$x_a^i$` vs `$x^i_a$`)?

Comment: I say `$x_{i}^{2}$`, because in most cases you want to square the thing identified by a subscript, not identify a squared value with a subscript.

Answer (score 12):

The output by the TeX engine is the same in both situations. So the only question is whether one of them is more semantical than the other one. For example if `$x_i^2$` means `square of the $i$th item of a sequence $x$`, then it's more semantical to write it this way, rather than as `$x^2_i$`. But this depends on the situation, and also on how much pedantic you are :-)

Also, you should be consistent in your choice, it easies the editing of your files, both if you need to modify them, and if some professional editor (i.e., a person) needs to do so.

Last but not least, official LaTeX syntax requires braces for all superscripts and subscripts: `$x_{i}^{2}$`. Needless to say, hardly anybody follows this convention.

Comment: it's also a good idea to write all such expressions the same way throughout the document.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Good point.

Comment: Thanks, is there any standard order?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt As I explain, it's usually more natural to do `_^` than `^_`, so if you don't have any reason to do it the other way, stick to `_^`.

Comment: I totally agree with @barbara beeton. I have been asked by my supervisor to change some notations ( many many symbols). Without sticking with one notation, I couldn't use `find and relpace all` feature. Don't underestimate small stuff because you don't know when you have to modify your documents.

Comment: Um, what does "official LaTeX syntax" mean?

Comment: @Brian the latex syntax as specified in the latex book by Leslie Lamport.

Comment: I think you mean 'Needless to say...'?

Comment: @cfr Well, I mean "necessary to say", which is probably usually said as "needless to say". :-)

Answer (score 1):

Semantically speaking, you can consider them as postscript operators: the `_a` portion indexes into an array or vector or somesuch and the `^i` portion applies an exponent to a value. If you write `$x_a^i$`, you imply that you are indexing, and then applying an exponent. If you write `$x^i_a$`, you imply that you are applying an exponent to an entire vector, and then indexing into the result. You probably mean the former, `x_a^i`.

Lexicographically, the distinction is lost, because both of them produce the same result. With an extra pair of brackets, you can make it clear to your reader what is intended. If you type `${x_a}^i$`, the exponent is typeset so that it clearly applies to the `x_a` value.

Comment: With the exception when `$x$` is a sequence of sequences, `$x^{(i)}$` is the `$i$th` sequence in it, and `$x^{(i)}_j$` is the `$j$th` value in the `$i$th` sequence. Then, the superscript should go first, semantically speaking.

Comment: @yo' Excellent comment, as the `^` does not mean exponential in this case